# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{\left[\sqrt{n}\right]}\left(3^{\frac{1}{n}}-2^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**My Thoughts**:

The series can be written as:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^na_n a_n
& = \sum_{k=n^2}^{n^2+2n} \left(3^{\frac{1} {k}}-2^{\frac{1}{k}} \right)\\
&3^{\frac{1}{k}}-2^{\frac{1}{k}} = e^{\frac{\ln3}{k}}-e^{\frac{\ln2}{k}} \\
& = 1+\frac{\ln3}{k}+\frac{\ln^23}{2k^2}- \left(1+\frac{\ln2}{k}+\frac{\ln^22}{2k^2} \right)+O \left(\frac{1}{k^3} \right) \\
& = \frac{\ln\frac{3}{2}}{k}+\frac{\ln^23-\ln^22}{2k^2}+O \left(\frac{1}{k^3} \right)\\
&a_n\leq\sum_{k=n^2}^{n^2+2n}\frac{1}{n^4} \left(k\ln\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\ln^23-\ln^22}{2}+O \left(\frac{1}{k} \right) \right) \\
&=\frac{1}{n^4} \left( \left(n^2+n \right) \left(2n+1 \right)\ln\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\ln^23-\ln^22}{2} \left(2n+1 \right)+O \left(1 \right) \right) \\
& =\frac{2}{n}\ln\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\ln^23-\ln^22}{2}\frac{3}{n^2}+O \left(\frac{1}{n^3} \right)\\
&a_n \geq\sum_{k=n^2}^{n^2+2n}\frac{1}{ \left(n^2+2n \right)^2} \left(k\ln\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\ln^23-\ln^22}{2}+O \left(\frac{1}{k} \right) \right) \\
& \sim \frac{2}{n}\ln\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\ln^23-\ln^22}{2}\frac{3}{n^2}+O \left(\frac{1}{n^3} \right) \;\; \left(n \to +\infty \right)\\
&a_n-a_{n+1}\sim \frac{2}{n^2}\ln\frac{3}{2}+O \left(\frac{1}{n^3} \right)
\end{align}
So the series is convergent.

**My Problem**:

I don't know whether my last three steps are true or not (especially the last two steps).

Is there any other solution? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your argument is not quite right. inequalities of in one direction are follows by inequalities in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Revised answer thanks to the constructive suggestions by* [MartinR](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/42969/martin-r)

---

Starting from your work, since

$$3^{\frac{1}{n}}-2^{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac1n \log \frac32+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{\left[\sqrt{n}\right]}\left(3^{\frac{1}{n}}-2^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)
=\log \frac32\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left[\sqrt{n}\right]}}n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{\left[\sqrt{n}\right]}O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

then, since the second one converges absolutely, it suffices to study

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left[\sqrt{n}\right]}}{n}= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \sum_{i=k^2}^{k^2+2k} \frac1{i}$$

and we can conclude by alternating series test, indeed

$$A_k=\sum_{i=k^2}^{k^2+2k} \frac1{i} =H(k^2+2k)-H(k^2-1) = \frac 2 k+O\left(\frac1{k^2}\right)$$

then

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left[\sqrt{n}\right]}}{n}= 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}k +\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^kO\left(\frac1{k^2}\right)$$

and the second one converges absolutely.